# Use Ansible task output as hostlist in another task or play

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am attempting to run a playbook that is able to grab hosts dynamically.  We currently have a script that grabs hosts based on input parameters and outputs to stdout similar to:

```
host1
host2
host3
host4
```

Is there a way to have this information be used in the play

```
- name: Prep
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Grab Host List
      shell: somecommand.py
      register: hostlist
      changed_when: False
      always_run: yes

- name: Do something on Hosts from the previous play
  hosts: (host list from previous play)
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Do something on Hosts from the previous task
      shell: BlahBlah.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**hosts: (host list from previous play)**"*

A: Use [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html#ansible-builtin-add-host-add-a-host-and-alternatively-a-group-to-the-ansible-playbook-in-memory-inventory) and create new group of hosts, e.g.

```yaml
- name: Prep
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Grab Host List
      shell: somecommand.py
      register: hostlist
      changed_when: False
      always_run: yes
    - add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item }}"
        groups: new_group
      loop: "{{ hostlist.stdout_lines }}"

- name: Do something on Hosts from the previous play
  hosts: new_group
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Do something on Hosts from the previous task
      shell: BlahBlah.sh
```